# Highcharts: How to compare two series with different xAxis intervals in the same line chart

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, linegraph

I'm trying to compare two different date interval data in a single chart by using 'linkedTo' attribute (in order to vanish and show two lines in a single click of a legend since they are related)

My problem: two series are automatically align themselves in the middle ([Fiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/fp8mc7Lg/3/))

Here's my options:

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {


  xAxis: [{
    tickInterval: 1,
    left: 0
  },
  {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['4/18/2018', '4/19/2018', '4/20/2018', '4/21/2018', '4/22/2018', '4/23/2018'],
    visible: false,
    left: 0,
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
          return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b/%e/%Y', this.value);
        }
     }
  },
  {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['5/2/2018', '5/3/2018', '5/4/2018'],
    visible: false,
    
  }
  ],
  yAxis: [{
    type: 'value',
    visible: false
  },
  ],
  series: [{
      name: 'instance1',
      key: 'instance1',
      type: 'line',
      data: [1, 5, 2, 2, 8, 6
      ],
      xAxis: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'instance1 compared',
      linkedTo: 'instance1',
      dashStyle: 'shortdash',
      type: 'line',
      data: [
      8, 3, 6
      ],
      xAxis: 2
    }
  ],
  tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table><tr><th colspan="2">{point.key}</th></tr>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td>{series.name} </td> <td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>'
  },

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

What I want is something like here:
[Where the days are ticked together and short serie is halted before the other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXbnk.png)

I tried linking the two series in a single xAxis that tracks the day count as the picture. That partially worked to align the dots together but then I couldn't send the separate date data to tooltip. How can I format the tooltip?

Another solution I tried to find online is if there's any way I can link three data in highchart then I can use the day count as a single xAxis and put the date data in tooltip separately.
Ex: (125 clicks, 1/8/2022, Day: 2)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `max` property to the xAxis with fewer categories, in order to match it to the other one.

```
  xAxis: [{
      tickInterval: 1
    },
    {
      categories: categories1,
      visible: false
    },
    {
      categories: categories2,
      max: categories1.length - 1,
      visible: false
    }
  ],

  tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table><tr><th colspan="2">Day {point.point.x}</th></tr>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td>{point.category} </td> <td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>'
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/naes6v89/

Another approach you mentioned would be possible to achieve by using `series.keys` (API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.keys), but in this case, is not necessary. You need to only pass the category as a `point.name`, and then use the `point.x` value in `tooltip.headerFormat`

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true,
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true,
    headerFormat: '<table><tr><th colspan="2">Day {point.x}</th></tr>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td>{point.name} </td> <td style="text-align: right"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
  },

  series: [{
      name: 'instance1',
      id: 'instance1',
      data: [
        ['4/18/2018', 1],
        ['4/19/2018', 5],
        ['4/20/2018', 2],
        ['4/21/2018', 2]
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'instance1 compared',
      linkedTo: 'instance1',
      dashStyle: 'shortdash',
      data: [
        ['5/2/2018', 8],
        ['5/3/2018', 3],
        ['5/4/2018', 6]
      ],
    }
  ]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8xsnr7c9/

P.S. Remember you need to use `linkedTo` with `id`, instead of key.

```
 series: [{
      name: 'instance1',
      id: 'instance1',
      data: [1, 5, 2, 2],
      xAxis: 1
    },
    {
      name: 'instance1 compared',
      linkedTo: 'instance1',
      dashStyle: 'shortdash',
      data: [8, 3, 6],
      xAxis: 2
    }
  ]
```

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.linkedTo